# Put on new line while maintaning indentation in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Both <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and `:lineput` cause the text to be pasted at the beginning of the line. I want a way to paste text as if I hit <kbd>o</kbd> and just started typing.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may find [vi.SE] more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CTRL-R 0` (zero).

Why it is good explains this nice video [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/pasting-from-insert-mode/).

More about it you can find in Vim

```
:h i_ctrl-r
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<C-r>"` to put from the unnamed register or `<C-r>a` to put from register `a`.

See `:help i_ctrl-r`.